# Value of entity added on Luis disappeared

Tags: entity, azure-language-understanding

I've been using Luis for couple months and I felt like I'm getting used to it. But yesterday I had some change on my Entity which I had created couple months back. I added some values and it was total of 17 values(multiple synonyms for each value).

I tested and published the app and tested my program using the app and was working perfectly. But this morning when I used my app it was not working correctly. And when I checked the Entity which I added values yesterday, only had 6 values instead of 17. I was little worried because I had not take the backup of my app yesterday. I was checking other Entities too if they were also altered. But no other entities were altered. After checking all other entities and intents I checked the changed Entity again and there was all 17 values as it was yesterday. I was really confused what was going on. Then I started working on my program and after some 10 minutes or so, same thing happened. I did same as earlier and checked every other entities and intents and returned to that entity and there was 17 values again. From that particular time its not changed. Is there anyone who's experienced this weird thing while using Luis?

Comment: Can you please share your App Id so that we can investigate the issue.

Comment: @JyotsnaSudhaFanidam My app ID is
bd24849f-1721-482b-b35d-a5327dd0f139

Comment: @JyotsnaSudhaFanidam 
I would like to add some other weird things that I've experienced. While registering the synonyms on entity, it automatically get registered while I'm still typing (as if I've pressed the enter, but I actually did not). By the way, I'm using Google Chrome browser.

Comment: Can you please let us know if there is any issue now?

Comment: That was the only day I faced that problem multiple times. About the comment that I added later, its still the same.

Comment: Can you please share .HAR file from the chrome developer console when you are trying to reproduce the issue to Luisuservoice@microsoft.com so that we can investigate further.

Comment: Hi, we are experiencing the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?